# Uniform convergence in open disk

Tags: partial-derivative, uniform-convergence

I'm studying uniform convergence of harmonic function. In the course of studying, There is a part that I cannot understand. It is as follows

> Suppose that $u_n(x,y)$ are $C^1$ functions on an open set $R$ for $n \ge 0$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_n(x,y)$ converges uniformly to u(x,y) and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_n(x,y)$ converges uniformly to $v(x,y)$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_(x,y)=v(x,y)$
>
> pf. It is enough to **verify the theorem on a small square about an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0)$ in R. By limiting ourselves to a square, the whole line segment from $(x_0,y)$ to $(x,y)$ will lie in R**. We define function on this small square by
>
> $$ w_n(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(x_0,y)+\int_{x_0}^{x}**\frac{\partial}{\partial x}**\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(t,y)dt$$
>
> $$w(x,y)=u(x_0,y)+\int_{x_0}^{x}v(t,y)dt$$
>
> since the integrands $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(t,y)$ converge uniformly to $v(t,y)$ Corollary 8.3.2 shows that $w_n(x,y)$ converges uniformly to $w(x,y)$. But this limit is $u(x,y). Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculas,
>
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}w(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(u(x_0,y)+\int_{x_0}^{x}v(t,y)dt\big)(x,y)=v(x,y)$$

I have some question above proof.

Q1. Why do we suffice to "verify the theorem on a small square about an arbitrary point$(x_0,y_0)$"?

Q2. Is that correct above notation "$\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(t,y)dt$"?

I think $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ may be changed for $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ right?

I will wait your help. Thank you!

cf corol 8.3.2 [image]